# Remove html markup by wordpress

Tags: html, editor

I am recently creating a website for my company. I found there are many unnecessary markup by wordpress. I have provided screenshot and sample of the markup that i am referring to.

```
    </ol>
<!-- /wp:list --> <--this is one of the unnessary markup that i meant. There are so many and so on.

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>*This package gives you the best experience as all swing doors/drawers come with soft-closing door hinges to ensure each door closes softly and quietly.</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:heading {"level":3} -->
<h3>Upgrade to be Different</h3>
<!-- /wp:heading -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>This package, default is melamine abs. Bored of melamine abs? You have the option of upgrading the melamine to other door styles and worktop. Please read further. We have the best deal for the upgrade.</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p><strong>Door style</strong></p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->

<!-- wp:list -->
<ul>
```

Here is the screenshot.
[image]
I'd like to ask if there is any solution to remove all these by inserting any php code to the functions.php?

Thank you!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, those HTML comments (and that particular structure e.g. `/wp:paragraph`) are what Gutenberg uses to convert back to Gutenberg blocks if you convert to the Classic Editor and then back to Gutenberg. It basically assigns the tags to know what type of block to recreate. If you don't want that markup, you may need to switch to the Classic Editor.

Comment: Oh yea...i think so. I will switch it back to classic editor and try it out later. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions will allow you to strip out the Wordpress Block markup.
This will reduce the content to standard HTML element tags. Some associated Wordpress content will be removed: example. Reusable blocks, Query parameters. You may also lose some HTML attributes and their values.

You may find an suitable regular expression in the following thread.
[how to remove html comments in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337332/how-to-remove-html-comments-in-php)